# Slider overlay menu and toggle

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, nivo-slider

I have a problem with the Nivo SLider.The slider works correctly but I have a dropdown menu and a toggle that,when "activated",have to be over the slider image and not underneath as it is now.
This is [the link to my site][1].

to see the problem you have to go over the menu voice "PRODOTTI" or click on the labels "CERCA" or "AREA RISERVATA".
I've alredy tried to modify the z-indexes with no result.

Comment: I would like to let you know that z-index works if position is set , so check if position is set to absolute or relative

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems it's related to Nivo Slider. You have overflow: hidden on  .header and .menu2 and I believe that cause the problem.

Comment: Awesome!Thak you very much!I've lost my mind in such a dumb problem!Thaks!:)